# bakeResults is baking other attributes too

Tags: python, maya

I am having issues when using `cmds.bakeResults` to bake out the constraints channels (those highlighted in green).

In my case I am targetting it towards only the translation and rotation channels, should it be visible in the selection.

- It is not setting the keyframe towards any of the channels. still remains green...
- It seems to have keyframe all my other non-constraint channels and also setting the value of  the `blendParent` from 1 to 0. At a specified frame, I have keyframe the `blendParent` to use the value of 1 (in step mode), but this was overriden and it becomes 0 in the process.

This is my code portion:

```
# `sel` is a defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'schoolBoy01:L_leg_mainIk_ctrl': ['translateX', 'translateY', 'translateZ', 'rotateX', 'rotateY', 'rotateZ']})
cmds.bakeResults(
    sel,
    at=selAttrs.get(sel),
    simulation=True,
    time=(frame_range[0], frame_range[1]),       
    preserveOutsideKeys=True,
)
```

For the above 2 points, is that the supposed Maya behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

`bakeResults` won't break the connections from the pairBlend and constraint, but it will still bake the motion to keys so when the pairBlend is deleted the motion from the constraint will remain.

The reason your `blendParent` is keyed to 0 is because the pairBlend is still live, so it keys to 0 to use your newly baked keys.

As far as it keying your other attributes, you may need to check your values to make sure you aren't inputting wrong attributes. It seems to key only specific attributes here.